# Visual C++ Function Description Like in C#

Tags: c++

In C#, If you simply typed `Console.WriteLine`, IntelliSense will show you a small tool-tip that describes the `WriteLine` function by telling that it prints a line into the Console etc. On the other hand, In C++ if you type `std::cout` IntelliSense the same. Instead it just tells you the functions' overloads and inheritance.

Question: **How could i get a C# like IntelliSense that provides me with a snippet descriptions about the functions while i am typing them** ? *Instead of going to the internet reading the description foreach function*.

Comment: You can't. VC++ shows a help tooltip if you add a comment (plain //) before that function but STL headers have not such comment (primary, I guess, to keep them small and as fast as possible to compile because they're heavy used).

Comment: If you use Visual Studio then here is answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0we08bk.aspx

Comment: @AdamFolwarczny: i mean for the default functions not the custom ones.